# Error executing jupyter notebook : ImportError: cannot import name '_RuleList'

Tags: python, jupyter

When I execute jupyter notebook command I get

```
 jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tornado import web
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 95, in <module>
    from tornado.routing import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_RuleList'
(my_project_env)
```

Comment: Please add versions of your Python, jupyter and tornado (the output of `python -V` and `pip list | grep -e 'tornado\|jupyter'`)

Comment: python -V
Python 3.7.1 and pip list | grep -e 'tornado\|jupyter'
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
tornado         5.1.1  
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Looks like you need to upgrade your Python packages, at least `tornado`. I'm afraid to give positive advice, because I don't know your system, but you may try `pip install --upgrade tornado`. No guarantees (a disclaimer) but let me know if it works :)